# Apache Impala: How to create a temporary in-memory table?

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I'm using Apache Impala and want to create a temporary in-memory table like in Hive's `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.

I also want this table to be automatically dropped after the session ends and to be invisible from other sessions, like Hive's temporary tables.

Can this be done in Impala?

Comment: Probably you can not. Why not use hive for it or use a subquery? if you have complex problems that must use temp table, pls let us know.

Answer (score 2):

Impala's [WITH clause](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_with.html#with) allows you to factor out complex, repeated subquery blocks into their own statements.  It is functionally similar to `CREATE VIEW` except that the definition does not persist beyond the execution of the query.

So it saves keystrokes and readability, and ought not be visible to another session.  However, it does not have the memory performance implications of a temp table in a traditional RDBMS scenario (if that's what you were going for).